# Data Entry Form in Drupal

Tags: forms

I am new to Drupal and somehow managed to create a website with some basic pages I required using views. One of the main functionality that I need is a data entry form where a logged in user can enter details about members of his/her team like name, age, etc and this too for variable number of members. So far I could not find anything related. Has anyone tried anything related to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add fields to the existing content types 'Article' or 'Page' or create a content type based on your requirement. 
Add fields name, age, etc

```
admin >> strucuture >> content types >> Add content type
```

path (/admin/structure/types/add)
or manage fields of the existing content type (add or delete) 
Ex: For Article content type you can manage fields at

> admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields